# jquery, setting css property to empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently studying the jquery `css()` method.

In the [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) documentation, it states

[image]

However, I'm not exactly sure what they meant by **used to cancel any style modification you have previously performed. It does not, however, remove a style that has been applied with a CSS rule in a stylesheet or  element.**.

So I looked up [MDN page on HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style), which states

[image]

I also experiment by setting one of the property of `HTMLElement.style` to `""` (i.e. an empty string)

[image]

So it seems that by setting `color` property of `d.style` to `""`, I have removed the value of `color` property, and the `color` property was not removed from `d.style`.

But what does the documentation mean by **It does not, however, remove a style that has been applied with a CSS rule in a stylesheet or  element.**

Comment: Inline styles, ie style attribute/property, override styles defined in stylesheets and style tags. By clearing out the value in inline styles it just means it's going to go back to using whatever the value maybe in stylesheets/style tags. It does not mean the actual property will be removed from the style object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **[`.css()` method](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** can remove **inline** styles (denoted by `style=""`):

```js
var target = document.getElementById('target');
$('#target').css('color', '');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="target" style="color: red">Target</div>
```

But **not** styling rules that have been defined in a CSS stylesheet:

```js
var target = document.getElementById('target');
$('#target').css('color', '');
```

```css
#target {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="target">Target</div>
```

Nor will it work for styling inside `<style>` tags written in the same file:

```js
var target = document.getElementById('target');
$('#target').css('color', '');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="target">Target</div>

<style>
#target {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

This is because the **[CSSStyleDeclaration object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration)** is a **read-only** interface to **[`Window.GetComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle)**, which is used to retrieve the stylesheets.

> The `Window.getComputedStyle()` method returns an object that reports the values of all CSS properties of an element **after** applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain.

**[`Element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)** returns a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object, and is also read-only:

> Styles should not be set by assigning a string directly to the style property (as in `elt.style = "color: blue;"`), since it is considered read-only, as the style attribute returns a CSSStyleDeclaration object which is also read-only.

jQuery's **[`css()` method](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** itself attempts to modify the style property, and thus it can only update inline styles:

> When using `.css()` as a setter, jQuery modifies the element's style property. [ ... ] Setting the value of a style property to an empty string — e.g. `$( "#mydiv" ).css( "color", "" )` — removes that property from an element if it has **already been directly applied**, whether in the HTML style attribute, through jQuery's .css() method, or through direct DOM manipulation of the style property. [ ... ] It does not, however, remove a style that has been applied with a CSS rule in a stylesheet or  element.

Comment: hi Obsidian, thank you very much for helping out. Do you mind if I ask how you became so knowledgeable? What is the learning path you have travelled? I want to learn how others have studied in the past, so I can become a better programmer :)

Comment: No problem, and that's kind of you to say... though I still have much to learn myself. I personally picked up my skills by working as a front-end developer for about a decade. The best advice I can give is to study reliable and official documentation like [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/), and learn through doing. Writing answers on StackOverflow really helps in that regard! And along that vein, StackOverflow is specifically a question-answer site, so I can't really give you any extended advice, but I do wish you luck, and hope that my answer helps you :)

Comment: thanks Obsidian! your answer definitely cleared up my confusion. So glad there are many people like you on stackoverflow helping people out.