# Background color not changing in Chrome when setting css in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

In my JQuery/JS I'm doing a check and changing the background color and border color of a button, it works fine in IE but in Chrome, Chrome doesn't set the color back to grey. IE changes, just not Chrome. When I look in the debugger at the rendered html it doesn't add the coloring, it's just not there!!! Funny thing is it adds the disabled property in Chrome, so the line of Jquery code that sets the color back to grey is def being called!

Here is my button, I initialize it with grey and being disabled

```
<button id="eventRegister" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-yb footer-button" style="background-color: grey !important; border-color: grey !important; display: none;" disabled>Register</button>
```

Then with a checkbox on the page for 'terms and services' I enable it and remove the grey color. But if the user un checks the checkbox and resets the button back to grey, in Chrome, it doesn't change the color. IE is fine!

```
$("#registerEventTerms").off('change').on('change', function () {
        if (this.checked)
            $("#eventRegister").css('background-color', '').css('border-color', '').prop('disabled', false);
        else
            $("#eventRegister").css('background-color', 'grey !important').css('border-color', 'grey !important').prop('disabled', true);
    });
```

FYI - I'm thinking it has something to do with my class 'btn-yb' located in my site.css file, that has these properties, but not sure

```css
.btn-yb {
  background-color: #008489 !important;
  color: white !important;
}

.btn-yb:hover,
.btn-yb:focus {
  color: white !important;
}

.btn-yb.disabled,
[disabled].btn-yb,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-yb {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
Also change your javascript


<script>
  src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" >
    $("#registerEventTerms").off('change').on('change', function() {
      if ($(this).prop('checked', true);)
        $("#eventRegister").css('background-color', '').css('border-color', '').prop('disabled', false);
      else
        $("#eventRegister").css('background-color', 'grey !important').css('border-color', 'grey !important').prop('disabled', true);
    });
</script>
```

**Change CSS**

```
  .btn-yb {
  background-color: #008489;
  color: white !important;
}

.btn-yb:hover,
.btn-yb:focus {
  color: white !important;
}

.btn-yb.disabled,
[disabled].btn-yb,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-yb {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: it's not a question of the check reaching the line of code or not, it is! The code even disables the button, it just doesn't set the css color. So I'm not sure if Chrome acts differently then IE when it comes to over riding elements css properties

Comment: remove !important from css 
.btn-yb{
 background-color: #008489;
}

Comment: ya that's it. why doesn't Chrome allow this but IE does??

Comment: @user1186050 did you get any any error in your chrome's javascript console.

Comment: No! I just tested it and looked in the console, nothing! Funny!

Answer (score 0):

Things are happening in the following order:

1. First, your inline `style` is getting applied, and setting the button's `background-color` to `grey`.
2. Next your stylsheet is setting the `background-color` to `#008489`.
3. Finally, your jQuery is removing the **inline** style successfully.

It's important to note that jQuery's **[`css()` method](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** attempts to modify the **[`style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)**, and thus it can only update **inline** styles, **not** external stylesheets. Your inline style is removed, and your stylesheet rule is not. As such, you see the stylesheet's `#008489` `background-color`.

Remember, inline styles have more specificity than stylesheet styles. This can **only** be overridden with `!important`. However, things get **much** more confusing with multiple `!important` declarations, as all your rules are essentially fighting for highest specificity. Avoid using `!important` whenever possible, opting for **[more specific CSS selectors](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)** instead.

The simplest solution to this is to just remove all of your `!important` declarations, as this will allow the specificity to be handled in the correct order:

```js
$("#registerEventTerms").off('change').on('change', function() {
  if (this.checked)
    $("#eventRegister").css('background-color', '').prop('disabled', false);
  else
    $("#eventRegister").css('background-color', 'grey').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```css
.btn-yb {
  background-color: #008489;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="eventRegister" type="button" class="btn-yb" style="background-color: grey" disabled>Register</button>
```

Alternatively, you can setup a new selector to target the `disabled` attribute, which would mean you don't need to worry about setting styles in **either** HTML or jQuery - all that needs to be handled is the `.prop()`:

```js
$("#registerEventTerms").off('change').on('change', function() {
  if (this.checked)
    $("#eventRegister").prop('disabled', false);
  else
    $("#eventRegister").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```css
.btn-yb {
  background-color: #008489;
  color: white;
}

.btn-yb[disabled] {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="eventRegister" type="button" class="btn-yb" disabled>Register</button>
```

For a more comprehensive reasoning of exactly why the `css()` method can modify inline styles but not stylesheet styles, please see **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49745173/2341603)** I wrote yesterday.

As for why IE is behaving differently than Chrome, I assume it's based on the order of specificity of how multiple `!important` statements are handled.